# Place SVG path-objects with coordinates to connect them (HTML)

Tags: html, css, svg

I am making interactive SVG-Map of United States, and created each state with SVG path and saved them to my directory

Now i need to place them ideally with coordinates (with no breaks between them)

Also each state will be interactive, so maybe I need to use one  tag for each

The problem is the SVG paths have no coordinates, just placing on the field created with  tag

Is there a way to place them like that?

I want something like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZJnE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `<svg>` element with a raster `<image>` as the background, then create an SVG `<path>` for each state, containing a `<title>` with the state name. **Note that I’ve only done the western states** in this example, but it gives you the idea.

I’d also recommend [Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com/) to set up your paths. Open the raster map in Boxy SVG, draw your paths around each state, give each path a title, save the file, then open the file in a text editor and copy the path information.

```css
.us-map path:hover {
    stroke: black;
    fill: black;
    stroke-width: 4px;
    fill-opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<svg class="us-map" viewBox="0 0 2347 1147" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<image width="1816" height="1186" href="https://donald.net.au/bugs/united-states.webp"></image>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 511.643 305.122 L 479.158 463.467 L 688.505 493.256 L 704.549 333.512 L 511.643 305.122 Z">
    <title>Wyoming</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 397.213 405.913 L 350.343 601.765 L 515.41 632.24 L 537.397 471.013 L 479.348 463.768 L 487.048 424.347 L 397.213 405.913 Z">
    <title>Utah</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 748.964 500.538 L 735.783 659.824 L 516.257 632.856 L 538.013 472.065 L 748.964 500.538 Z">
    <title>Colorado</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 218.683 360.113 L 396.597 405.422 L 342.666 632.388 L 323.278 626.727 L 314.383 650.526 L 318.529 670.298 L 313.35 676.233 L 185.011 481.511 L 192.605 468.058 L 188.088 460.034 L 218.683 360.113 Z">
    <title>Nevada</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 513.784 633.64 L 479.379 855.586 L 507.229 861.017 L 508.656 844.679 L 569.338 853.293 L 569.66 844.071 L 685.837 857.964 L 701.845 657.42 L 513.784 633.64 Z">
    <title>New Mexico</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 351.556 602.537 L 514.189 631.953 L 480.505 854.752 L 411.541 845.047 L 289.889 775.318 L 291.471 766.683 L 302.825 762.469 L 296.844 747.43 L 306.624 724.055 L 321.362 706.588 L 314.989 678.547 L 317.962 665.455 L 314.423 654.227 L 320.93 629.715 L 345.178 629.921 L 351.556 602.537 Z">
    <title>Arizona</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 97.605 322.715 L 88.441 326.166 L 94.096 338.013 L 82.728 355.158 L 83.809 366.435 L 64.827 384.738 L 74.074 406.35 L 74.631 419.624 L 70.468 439.361 L 62.095 446.509 L 70.672 449.807 L 82.886 478.858 L 75.425 487.413 L 84.179 494.62 L 99.557 487.111 L 133.617 492.355 L 100.238 496.349 L 101.643 512.065 L 91.053 507.309 L 85.473 543.911 L 92.514 550.423 L 92.621 562.619 L 105.656 596.614 L 116.276 608.671 L 113.313 640.015 L 118.182 652.5 L 141.499 659.836 L 184.2 689.662 L 178.883 698.399 L 180.915 703.735 L 200.114 703.566 L 198.894 716.395 L 211.447 732.427 L 205.095 749.795 L 212.257 749.958 L 212.42 757.009 L 301.641 765.387 L 298.347 747.165 L 307.599 722.124 L 320.9 706.163 L 314.157 677.026 L 184.996 480.051 L 190.932 463.826 L 185.245 459.866 L 218.444 360.7 L 97.605 322.715 Z">
    <title>California</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 190.409 182.94 L 161.124 168.189 L 160.454 182.98 L 143.85 200.45 L 137.129 215.035 L 136.067 224.818 L 101.495 286.629 L 90.699 287.851 L 96.133 296.133 L 97.409 322.27 L 313.2 385.955 L 349.297 263.843 L 364.281 255.17 L 350.243 227.491 L 292.559 211.943 L 229.292 211.877 L 192.076 195.992 L 190.409 182.94 Z">
    <title>Oregon</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 236.93 75.544 L 240.504 89.429 L 238.407 109.064 L 242.402 123.518 L 232.388 120.676 L 219.578 141.312 L 223.257 104.724 L 198.835 99.016 L 175.988 79.385 L 174.556 94.812 L 177.535 104.354 L 165.515 133.824 L 171.821 141.561 L 171.821 147.786 L 163.379 157.854 L 190.221 172.993 L 193.733 179.546 L 193.564 194.436 L 227.865 209.555 L 293.39 210.922 L 349.394 225.756 L 384.526 114.711 L 236.93 75.544 Z">
    <title>Washington</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 411.048 121.333 L 401.366 153.017 L 420.919 183.632 L 431.434 224.968 L 423.195 244.274 L 420.705 260.076 L 431.161 256.006 L 436.828 291.326 L 452.349 316.892 L 491.934 320.807 L 497.814 325.793 L 506.725 325.793 L 485.309 425.67 L 312.246 385.797 L 347.864 262.819 L 384.564 262.393 L 349.515 227.636 L 386.736 112.644 L 411.048 121.333 Z">
    <title>Idaho</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="transparent" d="M 412.018 120.703 L 401.983 153.058 L 421.195 185.412 L 432.453 226.671 L 423.571 242.467 L 420.072 260.092 L 431.461 255.931 L 437.483 291.846 L 452.759 316.144 L 492.806 321.061 L 496.878 325.646 L 507.028 326.397 L 510.321 305.93 L 706.137 333.04 L 724.575 175.707 L 412.018 120.703 Z">
    <title>Montana</title>
  </path>
</svg>
```